# adjacent duplicate remover function

Tags: c, recursion

I write a function that removes adjacent duplicate characters. Generally function works well but does not work in one place. what's wrong on there?

```
char *remove_duplicates (char *str) {
int i=0;
int j;
//  if(str[i]=='\0')
//  return; 

if(str[i]!='\0') {
    if(str[i]==str[i+1]) {
        //str[i+1]='0';
        j=0;
            while(str[j]!='\0') {
            str[j]=str[j+1];
            j++;
        }
        remove_duplicates(str+1);
    }
    else{
        remove_duplicates(str+1);

    }
    //i++;
}
```

My input is:  "Thiis is not completely misspelled butt we wannnnt to fix it"
I expect: “This is not completely mispeled but we want to fix it”
Result:“This is not completely mispeled but we wannt to fix it”

Comment: Try it with just `"nnn"` as input and see what happens.

Comment: I just solved this but I can't understand. The solution is that I wrote directly remove_duplicates(str+1);  instead of else{remove_duplicates(str+1);}

Comment: No, that doesn't really fix it.

Comment: Yes, I tried nnnn and it comes nn but I wrote my input sentence and it comes true. I can't understand what it does not at all.

Comment: Hint: add the following comment somewhere in your original code `/* removed one duplicate character, now rescan for the next duplicate */` then modify the next line of code to match the comment.

Comment: if(str[i]==str[i+1])remove_duplicates(str);                     this worked. thanks

Comment: Yes, indeed. You'll also notice that with this change the string becomes exactly one character shorter at each recursive call, which was probably the original intention.